# What is a hardware attachment for dowel rods that allow for running wire through the ends?

Tags: joinery, dowel

I made this tensegrity cube using dowel rods and eye screws. The eye screws were hard to install and didn't work well due to twisting and coming loose. I'm imagining a cap like hardware for dowels that allow you to attach other things. In this case running wire through them. Do such "caps" exist?

What is a hardware attachment for dowels rods that allow for running wire through the ends?

[image]

Comment: What about just drilling holes through the dowels for the wire?

Comment: @JasonC Depends on the strength required; holes could create a weak point, but if it's just to hang it, that's probably a good soultion.

Comment: Well if the problem is eye screws coming loose you could always throw an appropriate glue ([Loctite has some](http://www.loctiteproducts.com/p/cntct_wbndr/overview/Loctite-Wood-Bonder-3-Minute.htm) but just test with whatever in scrap) on the threads. @NipFu What is the diameter of the dowels and the wire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this location](http://wood-dowels.exceldowel.com/viewitems/dowel-rods-dowel-caps-finials/dowel-caps-and-connectors-plastic) (there may be others, but this came up almost immediately when I Googled "dowel caps".) for a selection of plastic dowel caps with eyelets. (see below from the afore mentioned link Unfortunately, at this location they want to sell them in quantities of 1000's.  I'm certain you can find sites that will sell to you in smaller amounts.

[image]

Functionally it should do the job for you.  It makes me consider doing some tensegrity constructions of my own.  Hey, I'm a child of the 60's. Myself, I would probably consider using wooden caps, but that's up to the designer/creator of the project.

Comment: I suggest including a picture of what you are describing in case the link goes dead. Hosting it with SE should ensure that does not happen.

Comment: Good idea, wilco.

Comment: Good point that a small block of wood, drilled for the doweland drilled for the cable, would work quite well

Comment: @Keshlam actually, I think that Tinker Toy rods would do the job - no caps needed.

Comment: A slice in the end of the dowel Yeah, I seem to remember some impressive structures being built that way.  Depends on load; I'd worry a bit about splitting. A block -- or a tinker toy hub -- could be stronger & have its grain orientedt better take that stress.